# Edge holes created from ArcPy script

Tags: arcpy, raster, polygon-creation

I'm working on creating floodplain polygons from Base Level Engineering Depth grids.

When running this script I end up with holes that don't get filled in on the edges, as circled in red in the image below. The purple is the resulting polygon and the black is the input raster.

I believe its because the NoData cell is not contained on all four edges and corners of the raster. Is there some modification to the code that can fill in these holes before converting to polygon?

```
'''-----------------------------------------------------------
Required Arguments:
             Input BLE Depth Grid (Raster)
             Target Geodatabase (Geodatabase)
Description: This tool takes BLE depth grid with horizontal
             and vertical units in feet and removes areas
             that are less than 0.25 acres or between 0.25 - 0.5
             acres and with average depth less than 0.5 feet or
             between 0.5 - 1 acres and average depth less than
             0.25 acres or between 1 - 2 acres and average depth
             less than 0.1 feet.
-----------------------------------------------------------'''
import arcpy, os


arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False


#matrix has been edited to change area from 0.25 acres to 0.3
matrix = """AREA <= 14374.8 Or 
(AREA > 14374.8 And AREA <= 21780 And MEAN < 0.5) Or 
(AREA > 21780 And AREA <= 43560 And MEAN < 0.33) Or 
(AREA > 43560 And AREA <= 87120 And MEAN < 0.1)"""

def applyMatrix(in_raster):
            
    in_raster = arcpy.Raster(in_raster)
    base_name = in_raster.name.split(".")[0]
    out_raster = arcpy.sa.Int(in_raster)
    out_raster = arcpy.sa.RegionGroup(out_raster, "FOUR", "CROSS", "NO_LINK", None)
    #Update for 2.7 to only have 6 arguments, not 7
    zsTable = arcpy.sa.ZonalStatisticsAsTable(out_raster, "Value", in_raster, r"memory\\zsTable", 
                                              "DATA", "MEAN")
    arcpy.management.JoinField(out_raster, "OBJECTID", zsTable, "OBJECTID", ["AREA","MEAN"])
    out_raster = arcpy.sa.SetNull(out_raster, out_raster, matrix)
    with arcpy.EnvManager(outputZFlag="Disabled", outputMFlag="Disabled"):
        polygon = arcpy.conversion.RasterToPolygon(out_raster, os.path.join(out_path, 'polygonX'), "NO_SIMPLIFY", "OBJECTID", "SINGLE_OUTER_PART", None)
    #Name error: Occurs when file starting with a number is saved to a geodatabase
    polygon = arcpy.management.EliminatePolygonPart(polygon, os.path.join(out_path, base_name + '_matrix_filled_poly'), 
                                          "AREA", "14374.8 SquareFeet", 0, "CONTAINED_ONLY")
    out_raster = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(in_raster, out_raster) 
    out_raster = (arcpy.sa.Int(out_raster*10 + 0.5))/10
    out_raster.save(os.path.join(out_path, base_name + '_matrix_raster'))
    arcpy.management.Delete(os.path.join(out_path, 'polygonX'))

if __name__ == '__main__':


    in_raster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    out_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

    applyMatrix(in_raster)

    applyMatrix(in_raster)
```

[image]

Comment: This kind of gap is called an *inversion*. It's handled the same way the large inversion to the north is handled. What do expect to happen with each?

Comment: I'd like it to fill in those inversions similarly to how the code is filling in the resulting purple polygon underneath.

Comment: But, topologically, the inversions are NOT inside the black polygon, just at the edge (as is the inversion near the mouth of the harbor).  You'd need to scan for repeating vertices to locate the inversions, or "repair" them using OGC rules, extract the holes, then manually code them.